# Import and export in one python script for FBX to IFC in Blender

Tags: scripting, export, import

I have many .fbx files that I need convert to .ifc files by using the BlenderBIM addon.

I am trying to do this as part of a regular workflow which is initiated from a .bat file. (the bat file will do other things before and afterwards but that part is not included)

```
"C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.90\blender.exe" --background "C:\Users\Joshua\Documents\_BatchProcessing\ProcessTemplate.blend" --python "C:\Users\Joshua\Documents\_BatchProcessing\FBXimportScript.py"
```

Which calls the python script

```
import bpy
import os
import glob

directory_im = 'C:/Users/Joshua/Documents/_BatchProcessing/max/fbx/test/'
files = glob.glob(directory_im + "*.fbx")
for f in files:
    head, tail = os.path.split(f)
    bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx(filepath=f)
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
    bpy.ops.object.parent_clear(type='CLEAR_KEEP_TRANSFORM')
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
    bpy.ops.export_ifc.bim(
    filepath=directory_im + tail.replace('.fbx', '') + '.ifc')
```

I have 2 FBX files to test which different geometry in each which can be seen by the different file size. the above python script exports 2 files with correct names however the same geometry is being exported to each file.
[image]

If someone could point me in the right direction it would be very much appreciated!!!

Comment: Not sure I understand, but each export will have all the previous FBXs included in the scene. Did you want to clear the scene at the beginning of the loop?

Comment: what happens is that the same geometry is in all the exported .ifc files. i thought if i added bpy.ops.scene.new(type='EMPTY') after the file export in the same For loop it would clear the scene and move onto the next fbx file this didn't work.

Comment: Try `bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT') ; bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False)` to clear the scene. But it might be better to do the loop in the .bat file and pass just one file to be converted to the .py script at a time.

Comment: I’ll give that a go. however i’m curious to know how to do the loop in the bat file, how might that work?

Comment: Nope that didn't work. I'm not sure i was clear enough before. The script exports the 'test1' file twice, test1.ifc and test2.ifc are identical when opened.

Comment: You can look up how to loop over files in a .bat on SO. You would pass the file to blender by adding `-- path\to\file.fbx` to the cmdline args, and in the .py script you'd get it with `sys.argv[sys.argv.index("--")+1]`.

Comment: Ok, i'll look into that

Comment: CMD Loop was the answer!

Answer (score 1):

A heads up for those reading this in 2021 that the BlenderBIM Add-on has since been completely rewritten and this script no longer applies. IFC is not a geometry format like FBX and so it isn't simply a matter of converting from one format to another. IFC instead requires a lot of semantic data, including a hierarchy of spaces, semantic classification of objects (e.g. not just a cube, but a "wall"), and more. As a result, you may be interested in looking at some of the operators available in the `bpy.ops.bim.*` namespace, or if you're looking for a geometry converter, I would instead recommend using more fundamental code seen in the `ifcopenshell.api.*` namespace.